# Question for ${\cal N}=1$ supersymmetry representations

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, supersymmetry, poincare-symmetry, superalgebra

Please see this lecture note: https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1491.

In section "2.2.5 Massless supermultiplet"
the author defines a Casimir and says it is zero.
How can we confirm it?
We take the frame where $p^\mu = (E,0,0,E)$.
The Casimirs are
\begin{equation}
C_1 = P^\mu P_\mu,\;\;
\tilde C_2 = C_{\mu\nu}C^{\mu\nu},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
B_\mu := W_\mu - \frac14\bar Q_{\dot\alpha}(\bar\sigma_\mu)^{\dot\alpha\beta}Q_\beta,\;\;
C_{\mu\nu} := B_\mu P_\nu - B_\nu P_\mu.
\end{equation}

For the first Casimir we can find easily $C_1 = -P_0P_0 + P_3P_3 = -E^2 + E^2 = 0$.
How to calculate the second one and is it really zero?

I show my calculation below.
For the second Casimir,
\begin{equation}
C_{01} = B_0P_1 - B_1P_0 = -EB_1,\;\;
C_{02} = -EB_2,\;\;
C_{03} = E(B_0 - B_3),\;\;
C_{12} = 0,\;\;
C_{13} = EB_1,\;\;
C_{23} = EB_2.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\tilde C_2 
= -2(C_{01}C^{01} + C_{02}C^{02} + C_{03}C^{03} + C_{13}C^{13} + C_{23}C^{23})
= -2E^2(B_0 - B_3)^2,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
B_0 - B_3
= W_0 - W_3 - \frac14\bar Q_{\dot\alpha}\bigg[
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0\\ 0& 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0\\ 0& -1
  \end{pmatrix}\bigg]^{\dot\alpha\beta}Q_\beta
= W_0 - W_3 - \frac12\bar Q_{\dot1}Q_1.
\end{equation}
How do we show this is zero?

Comment: Check chapter 4 of the Muller-Kirsten/Wiedermann SUSY book it's probably in there.

Answer (score 0):

We take the frame where $p^\mu = (E,0,0,E)$.
The components of $W_\mu$ are
\begin{align}
W_0 &= -\epsilon_{0312}P^3M^{12} = EJ_3,\;\;
W_1 = -\epsilon_{1023}P^0M^{23}
 - \epsilon_{1302}P^3M^{02}
= E(-J_1 + K_2),\\
W_2 &= -\epsilon_{2031}P^0M^{31}
 - \epsilon_{2301}P^3M^{01}
= E(-J_2 - K_1),\;\;
W_3 = -\epsilon_{3012}P^0M^{12} 
= -EJ_3,\\
W_\mu &= E(J_3,-J_1+K_2,-J_2-K_1,-J_3).
\end{align}
In the above we used
$J_i = (1/2)\epsilon_{ijk}M^{jk},\;\;K_i = M^{i0}$ and
$\epsilon_{123} = \epsilon^{0123} = 1$.
Their commutators are
\begin{align}
[W_1,W_2] &= E^2[-J_1 + K_2,-J_2 - K_1]
= E^2(i\epsilon_{123}J^3 + (-i\epsilon_{123}J^3))
= 0,\\
[W_3,W_1] &= E^2[-J_3,-J_1 + K_2]
= E^2(i\epsilon_{312}J^2 - i\epsilon_{321}K^1)
= E^2i(J^2 + K^1)
= -iEW_2,\\
[W_2,W_3] &= E^2[-J_2-K_1,-J_3]
= E^2(i\epsilon_{231}J^1 - i\epsilon_{312}K^2)
= iE^2(J^1 - K^2)
= -iEW_1.
\end{align}
To define a new Casimir we introduce $C_{\mu\nu} = B_\mu P_\nu - B_\nu P_\mu$,
where $B_\mu := W_\mu - (1/4)\bar Q_{\dot\alpha}(\bar\sigma_\mu)^{\dot\alpha\beta}Q_\beta$.
\begin{equation}
C_{01} = B_0P_1 - B_1P_0 = -EB_1,\;\;
C_{02} = -EB_2,\;\;
C_{03} = E(B_0 + B_3),\;\;
C_{12} = 0,\;\;
C_{13} = EB_1,\;\;
C_{23} = EB_2.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\tilde C_2 
= -2(C_{01}C^{01} + C_{02}C^{02} + C_{03}C^{03} + C_{13}C^{13} + C_{23}C^{23})
= -2E^2(B_0 + B_3)^2,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
B_0 + B_3
= W_0 + W_3 - \frac14\bar Q_{\dot\alpha}\bigg[
  \begin{pmatrix}
  -1& 0\\ 0& -1
  \end{pmatrix}
  -
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0\\ 0& -1
  \end{pmatrix}\bigg]^{\dot\alpha\beta}Q_\beta
= EJ_3 + (-EJ_3) + \frac12\bar Q_{\dot1}Q_1
= \frac12\bar Q_{\dot1}Q_1.
\end{equation}
By taking the square,
\begin{equation}
\tilde C_2 
= -\frac12E^2\bar Q_{\dot1}Q_1\bar Q_{\dot1}Q_1
= -\frac12E^2\bar Q_{\dot1}(-\bar Q_{\dot1}Q_1 + 2(\sigma^\mu)_{1\dot1}P_\mu)Q_1,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\sigma^\mu P_\mu 
= E\bigg[\begin{pmatrix} -1& 0\\ 0&-1 \end{pmatrix}
 + \begin{pmatrix} 1& 0\\ 0&-1 \end{pmatrix}\bigg]
= E\begin{pmatrix}0& 0\\ 0&-2\end{pmatrix},\;\;
\therefore 
(\sigma^\mu P_\mu)_{1\dot1} = 0.
\end{equation}
Then we conclude that $\tilde C_2 = 0$.

I think I could reach a satisfactory answer by myself.
($\star$ I used the metric signature $\eta^{\mu\nu} = (-1,+1,+1,+1)$ above unlike the text.)
However, I think this was so complicated calculation.
If you can give a proof in more simple way, please tell me.. (*´Д｀人)